# Find all elements with class="x" and POST to server for database INSERT

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, coldfusion, loops

Given a large text block from a WYSIWYG like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="X" id="12">consectetur adipiscing elit</span>. Donec interdum, neque at posuere scelerisque, justo tortor tempus diam, eu hendrerit libero velit sed magna. Morbi laoreet <span class="X" id="13">tincidunt quam in facilisis.</span> Cras lacinia turpis viverra lacus <span class="X" id="14">egestas elementum. Curabitur sed diam ipsum.</span>
```

How can I use JQUERY to find the following:

```
<span class="X" id="12">consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
<span class="X" id="13">tincidunt quam in facilisis.</span>
<span class="X" id="14">egestas elementum. Curabitur sed diam ipsum.</span>
```

And post it to the server as follows:

```
12, consectetur adipiscing
13, tincidunt quam in facilisis.
14, egestas elementum. Curabitur sed diam ipsum.
```

In such a way that ColdFusion can loop through the results and make 3 inserts into the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var postText = "";
$("span.X").each(function() {
     postText += "\n" + $(this).attr("id") + ", " + $(this).text();
});

$.ajax({
   url: "path/to/script",
   type: "POST",
   data: "postText=" + postText,
   success: function(response) {
      // request has finished at this point.
   }
});
```

Comment: should be `$("span.X")` - without space between span and .X

Comment: So what is the end result here? Is it posting an array? What am I doing on the backend to insert into the DB? thxs